# C# fill data to excel.range not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` for writing data to excel

Now I'm using below code to fill data to a range of cells. Let's say from P10 to P20

```
    Excel.Worksheet ps_sheet = //current worksheet
    string[,] data = new string[11,1];
    var  r = ps_sheet.Range["P10", "P20"];
    r.Value2 = data;
```

The above code is working properly, but if there's only one cell in the range (e.g. "P20" to "P20") the code won't work, the cell is showing the old data.

```
    Excel.Worksheet ps_sheet = //current worksheet
    string[,] data = new string[1,1];
    var  r = ps_sheet.Range["P20", "P20"];
    r.Value2 = data;
```

The excel.range can have one cell only or have multiple cells, since I'm doing a loop.

Is there any reason why this situation happens and how to fix?

Comment: I think it's not including the last number that's why when you give the same place it's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only one parameter, second parameter is optional

```
 var  r = ps_sheet.Range["P20"];
```

[**Worksheet.Range Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I changed to below code and it works:

```
    if (data.GetLength(0) == 1)
    {
        r = ps_sheet.Range["P10"];
        r.Value2 = data[0, 1];
    }
    else
    {
        r = ps_sheet.Range["P10", "P20"];
        r.Value2 = data;
    }
```

I specially made a case if the data has only one row...
Don't know if there're any better ways to achieve this